# jQuery onClick code only firing for first element

Tags: jquery

I am finding trouble getting my thumbnails to open the larger images when clicked. It only seems to work with the first thumbnail, but I can't figure out why.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$('#main ul:first-child').show();

$('#thumb li').click(function(){
    var navItem = $(this).index();
    $('#main ul').hide();
    $('#main ul:nth-child('+(navItem+1)+')').show();
    return false;
});

$('#main ul a').colorbox();

});
</script>
```

Any help??

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.hide()` on the `<ul>`. That will hide the entire structure; subsequently making the nested `<li>` components visible won't have any effect because the parent is hidden.

Instead of that, hide all the `<li>` elements:

```
  $('#main ul li').hide();
```

That will hide all the `<li>` children where (presumably) your large images reside. Then, your next line of code will show the one you want to show (the one corresponding to the clicked thumbnail).

Comment: So leave it like this?
 $('#main ul:first-child').show();
 
 
 $('#thumb li').click(function(){ 
          
 var navItem = $(this).index(); 
 
 $('#main ul li').hide();
 
 return false;
That just hides everything...

Comment: No no, you still need to call `.show()` on the one that has been selected.

Comment: $('#main ul:first-child').show();
 
 
 $('#thumb li').click(function(){ 
          
 var navItem = $(this).index(); 
 
 $('#main ul li').hide();

 
 $('#main ul:nth-child('+(navItem+1) +')').show();
 
 return false;
          
}); It is still hiding everything....

Comment: Is everything ok with this line?   $('#main ul:nth-child('+(navItem+1) +')').show();

Comment: @adennis Yes, I *think* it looks OK; so long as your thumbnail `<li>` and "full-size" `<li>` elements are properly paired up it should work I think.  (Not 100% sure about the "+ 1" part, but it should be easy to tell :-)  You should use a debugger or something to make sure that the call to `.index()` is returning what you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's the entire code, you have an error on the last line of the script:

```
$('#thumb li').click(function(){

  [snip]

});

$('#main ul a').colorbox();

});
```

The `});` doesn't belong to anything. In this case, if you check your browser's javascript console, you'll most likely see the error on that line.